# How to add notes to iCloud via sending an email

Tags: icloud, email, notes.app

I use a lot of notes apps on my iPad IOS 7, and I like the option of adding a note via sending the note to a custom email address instead of opening the app and adding the note manually (Like evernote for example).

Still, I couldn't find such functionality regarding iCloud Notes ! I have iCloud Notes syncing my notes from two sources

(1) from my iDevices and (2) from my gmail notes folder
In Gmail, I tried sending an email to myself; forwarding; and auto labeling them, that did move the emails to notes folder but they did not sync to iCloud.

I have searched pages and pages of google and noooo clue. Does anyone have any idea or a workaround to apply this on iCloud notes ?

Answer (score 2):

Although I, personally, do not use the Notes.app (preferring Simplenote) my Wife uses the Notes.app in conjunction with her gmail account.

So if you have a gmail account it has a notes label that will add emails with that label to your notes.

It should be easy enough to create a rule to route any emails to that address with a specific phrase in the subject line to mark it as read and with the notes label.

This is not exactly what you were looking for. It requires a gmail account which may be a no-starter for some people, and I don't think that Apple has a way to create a note from an email other than copy/paste. But it might be worth looking into.